# rendering html elements in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am playing around with Arcgis, a mapping tool.

It has an api in python which I have downloaded and gotten to work properly (it imports and runs properly).

My problem is that the map is not being rendered within my IDE (VSCode, PyCharm or DataSpell). When I open the notebook inside of my browser, the map shows up properly and it can be interacted with etc. I believe the map itself is made using html but the IDE's im using are unable to display the maps. Is there a setting or a package I can download to show the map?

Expected Behavior:

This code:

```py
from arcgis.gis import GIS

gis = GIS()

m = gis.map("Berlin")
display(m)
```

should display [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nx9Ee.jpg).

Rather it displays [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCTQy.png).

How would I get the HTML/Map render to be displayed inside of my IDE?